# Error passing parameters from Java to Python?

Tags: java, python, parameters

This is my Java code for the click event of a button. What I'm trying to do is to pass a parameter to a python file which I am calling ... But I am getting error for `args[0]` and `args[1]` (`cannot find symbol`).

How can I avoid this problem? How do I pass parameters to a Python file that I'm calling in this fashion?

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

try { 
    PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), new String[0]);
    PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();

    interp.set("firstName", args[0]);
    interp.set("lastName", 1);
    interp.execfile("‪C:\\Users\\aswin-pc\\Desktop\\pythontest.py");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: args is not declared in this method, so it cannot me referenced. What do you want to do? Is args the array holding the launch arguments of your Java program?

Comment: I want to pass parameters to python from java, tell me any way to do it..

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because `args[0]` and `args[1]` are only accessible in Java from within the main method:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0])    // You can access it here!
    }

    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        System.out.println(args[0])    // Will throw exception, you can't access it here!
    }
}
```

You should instead try to pass your `args` to your class when you create it:

```
public class Test {

    private String[] args;

    public Test(String[] args) {
        this.args = args;    // Sets the class args[] variable from the passed parameter
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test myTest = new Test(args);
    }

    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        System.out.println(args[0])    // You can now access the class variable args from here!
    }
}
```

Comment: public static void main(String args[]) {
  
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new test1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });     if our main contains this, then how would I pass it

Comment: You will need to grab the `args[]` that the main method provides and copy them into a `final` String array you declare outside of the Runnable. This will allow you to access this new (copied) array inside of the Runnable object you're creating. The rest is then the same as in my answer.

Comment: now I did the same, no error is coming but the frame is coming in minimized form and the button in it is not there.. I don't know what error is occurring now. Help me

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really help you without asking to see more code, which is diverging away from the original topic of this question. Here on StackOverflow, we try and keep questions and answers concise and uncluttered, so if you cannot solve it yourself then perhaps post another question on StackOverflow that is specific to that issue. I hope that helps :)

Comment: My problem is I want to pass parameters to Python when calling from Java, but I am getting error on that args part. If you can tell me any other way to do it, it would be of great help.